# how to make gulp to recognize the @ path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gulp

when I run gulp command in my project(react 18), shows error:

```
src/service/chat/ConversationItemService.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/request/conversation/ConversationItemReq' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/chat/ConversationService.ts(2,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/request/conversation/ConversationReq' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/goods/GoodsService.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/common/XHRClient' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/goods/GoodsService.ts(3,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/iapproduct/IapProductAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/images/ImageService.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/images/ImageAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/images/ImageService.ts(2,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/common/XHRClient' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/user/FeedbackService.ts(1,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/user/UserAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

seems the gulp could not recognize the @ path, I am configured the @ path in tsconfig.json `"typescript": "^4.9.5",` like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
}
```

and the webpack 5 config like this:

```
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const path = require("path");
 
module.exports = override(
     config =>{
         config.resolve.alias = {
             "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
         };
         return config;
     },
);
```

the @ path works fine with my project, seems the gulp could not realize the path. is it possible to fix this issue? what should I do to fix it? This is the gulp version:

```
➜  ai-web git:(main) ✗ gulp --version
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

I have tried specify the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
➜  ai-web git:(main) ✗ gulp --project tsconfig.json
[13:43:20] Using gulpfile ~/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/gulpfile.js
[13:43:20] Starting 'default'...
[13:43:20] Starting 'typescript'...
[13:43:20] Starting '<anonymous>'...
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts(39,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
src/models/types/png.d.ts(3,20): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
src/page/component/hoc/withConnect.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/types/AppState' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/chat/ConversationItemService.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/request/conversation/ConversationItemReq' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/chat/ConversationService.ts(2,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/models/request/conversation/ConversationReq' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/goods/GoodsService.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/common/XHRClient' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/goods/GoodsService.ts(3,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/iapproduct/IapProductAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/images/ImageService.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/images/ImageAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/images/ImageService.ts(2,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/common/XHRClient' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/user/FeedbackService.ts(1,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/action/user/UserAction' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/service/user/FeedbackService.ts(2,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/common/XHRClient' or its corresponding type declarations.
TypeScript: 11 semantic errors
TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[13:43:22] '<anonymous>' errored after 2.48 s
[13:43:22] Error: TypeScript: Compilation failed
    at Output.mightFinish (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:131:43)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:66:22
[13:43:22] 'typescript' errored after 2.48 s
[13:43:22] 'default' errored after 2.48 s
```

Comment: You may want to check the TypeScript version being used by Gulp and ensure that it matches the one in your project.  Also, you can try explicitly specifying the tsconfig.json file when running the Gulp task using the      --project option.